# Detecting the duration of simulation

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a simulation which will run for several hours in Simulink. Is it possible to detect see total duration of simulation in Matlab or Simulink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tic`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html)/[`toc`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toc.html) does this. `tic` starts the timer, `toc` ends it. Time is given in seconds, adjust according to your needs.

```
tic
% code here
time = toc;
frpintf('It took %f s',time)
```